# confused on the logic SQL (log Triggers)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am confused on the logic of this question, my prof did not teach us anything regarding this.... can someone explain it to me and this is my horrible example of what i did> i definitely need to fixed the 
Inserted information and the stored values.

Create A trigger called TR_5 to log changes made to the CostPerHour of the services. When change is made to the CostPerHour add a record to the CostPerHourLog table (shown below). However, DO NOT record a change if the value of the CostPerHour did not change! Show the code to create the trigger and to create the table. All the table attributes are required.

```
Create Table CostPerHourLog
  (
    LogID [int]Identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ChangeDateTime smalldatetime, 
    ServiceCode varchar(15),
    Description varchar(100),
    OldCostPerHour smallmoney,
    NewCostPerHour smallmoney
  )
  Drop trigger TR_5

  go
  Create trigger TR_5
  on CostPerHour 
  for update
  as
  if @@rowcount<0 
  begin
    if not exists (select * from costperhourlog) 
    insert into CostperHourLog
    (LogID,ChangeDateTime,ServiceCode,Description,OldCostPerHour,NewCostPerHour)
    Values
    (LogID,ChangeDateTime,ServiceCode,Description,OldCostPerHour,NewCostPerHour)
    end
return
```

Comment: What exactly are you tring to do?

Comment: i am trying to log new infromation into my trigger... i am confuesed on how to insert and store values .... this is the question\\Create A trigger called TR_5 to log changes made to the CostPerHour of the services. When change is made to the CostPerHour add a record to the CostPerHourLog table (shown below). However, DO NOT record a change if the value of the CostPerHour did not change! Show the code to create the trigger and to create the table. All the table attributes are required.
         edited the question to be more legible

Comment: Please read up about triggers in BOL. You are definitely lost :)

Comment: Read up https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189799.aspx to find out more about how to use triggers - specifically look up the examples at the end taking note of the "inserted" table. This contains all rows that correspond to the UPDATE statement that was issued. you can use this to find out what has changed and then perform your log insert.

Comment: the triggers shown online have been 100% incorrect, i got help. however i just need to figure out the logic.... mycode is smooth as it gets now..just my logic is still off .

Answer (score 0):

```
    ALTER TRIGGER TR_5
   ON CostPerHour
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    if exists(select *  from inserted except select  * from deleted)
    begin
        insert into CostPerHourLog          
    end

END
GO
```